# How to replace a set of character values in a variable with another set of values in R

Tags: r

I have a data table `stats.marks2` which has 4 variables namely `"Subject", "Variable", "Sem1", "Sem2"`.

Under "Variable" the character values are `"n_", "mean_", "sd_", "q1_", "median_", "q3_", "minmax"`.

I have to replace

```
"n_" by "n", 
"mean_" by "Mean", 
"sd_" by "SD", 
"q1_" by "Q1",
"median_" by "Median", 
"q3_" by "Q3" and 
"minmax" by "Min, Max".
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A sample of the data would be appreciated.

Using `stringr` and `dplyr` and assuming `stats.marks2` is your data :

```
stats.marks2 %>% mutate(Variable = str_to_upper(str_replace(Variable, '_', '')))
```

EDIT : Since what you want to do is too complex for a single pattern, let's define each replacement using an array within `str_replace_all`

```
stats.marks3 %>%
  mutate(Statistics = str_replace_all(Statistics, 
                                      c("n_" = "n",
                                        "mean_" = "Mean",
                                        "sd_" = "SD",
                                        "q1_" = "Q1",
                                        "median_" = "Median",
                                        "q3_" = "Q3",
                                        "minmax" = "Min, Max")
                                      ))
```

Comment: Sample data: stats.marks3<-data.table(Subject=c("English","English","English","English","English","English"
                                   ),
                         Statistics=c("n_","mean_","sd_","q1_","median_","q3_"
                                      ),
                         sem1=c(4,46.25,2.0615,41,46.5,48))With the above code, I am getting N, MEAN, SD, Q1, MEDIAN, Q3, MINMAX. But I need n, Mean, SD, Q1, Median, Q3 and "Min, Max"